# ClaimsAuthenticationManager vs. IAuthenticationFilter vs. OWIN Forms Authentication

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, asp.net-mvc-5, owin

.NET 4.5, MVC 5: ClaimsAuthenticationManager, IAuthenticationFilter, OWIN Forms Authentication, and ClaimsPrincipals are all new since I last touched my site's authentication functions. I've found a lack of clarity in all the docs that say *this* or *that* is the right way. I can't even tell which features are mutually exclusive.

[This document](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/07/03/understanding-owin-forms-authentication-in-mvc-5.aspx) says the old ASP.NET `FormsAuthenticationModule` doesn't support Claims, but the new OWIN doesn't support cookieless. Yet, I get the feeling that OWIN is intended to be the go-forward feature?

1. Does the product roadmap say which method is the go-forward for web-apps?
2. Is ClaimsAuthenticationManager synonymous with OWIN Forms Authentication for web apps?
3. Are the ClaimsAuthenticationManager and a global IAuthenticationFilter mutually exclusive?

A push in the right direction would be appreciated, my brain is fried on this.

Comment: Good question! Still no recipe for this fruit salad.+1

Comment: IMHO, we can just enable multiple modes of authentication using OWIN. All are claims based, we can plug-in any authentication mechanism as a middleware in the OWIN pipeline. However for Web Apps, OWIN as a hosting platform is not yet standalone, there is a project called as `Helios` that deals with this. I am also waiting for the next steps as it is not clear as to whether OWIN is the right way going forward.

Comment: I don't believe Microsoft will ever go back to supporting cookieless authentication sessions, since they are inherently less secure.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/03/23/securing-your-asp-net-mvc-4-app-and-the-new-allowanonymous-attribute.aspx

Comment: 0leg: you may have to back up that claim that cookieless is inherently less secure. By "inherently", you are saying "even assuming an ideal implementation", and I can't think of a reason that would be. For example, cookies are transmitted with each request just as other parameters are. The only risk I can think of is that video surveillance could allow replay, if all the key material is present in the visible area of the URL dialog. Also, requiring cookies has its own risks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### IAuthenticationFilter

Previously in MVC, `IAuthorizationFilter` was a common place to perform custom authentication. The reasoning for this filter can be seen in the scenario where an application has two authorization specifications, and only one authentication specification. Two options - adding the authentication specification to a single arbitrary authorization routine, and creating all three of these specifications as distinct `IAuthorizationFilter` - both mean we don't ensure that authentication occurs first.

`IAuthenticationFilter` was originally added to the MVC assembly to address this, then relocated for use by WebAPI as well. A good related article can be found here; [ASP.NET Web API Security Filters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn781361.aspx).

Strictly speaking, `IAuthenticationFilter` and OWIN Authentication are not mutually exclusive, but OWIN Authentication will happen first and can get in the way of any intent to use both.

### OWIN Forms Authentication

OWIN forms authentication is a confusing phrase that I got from reading an ill-phrased article (linked above). It represents two non-dependent solution components:

The "Forms" aspect of the solution still operates the same as it did for Forms Authentication previously. It's a consequence of authorization failure (such as that occurring from an `[Authorize]` attribute or a `web.config` `<authorization>` element) paired with a redirect to a logon-handler form. (Your choice of technology will determine where you configure that redirect URL. For OWIN, you'll configure it in `CookieAuthenticationOptions`.)

The "OWIN" aspect is more relevant to the confusion that prompted my OP. I won't go into much detail on OWIN broadly, as it's meant to do a lot more than authentication; entirely decoupling ASP.NET from IIS (via OWIN), it results in lots of pros and cons, but MVC6 is built exclusively on OWIN so it's here to stay.

Specific to Authentication, current modules like the ASP.NET external authentication providers (Facebook/Google social login) depend on OWIN. If you write ASP.NET web authentication [the "normal" way](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/security/create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-app-with-facebook-and-google-oauth2-and-openid-sign-on) you'll be using OWIN. This is a benefit to authentication via OWIN.

Previously, social login occurred in a more cobbled-together fashion as redirection and a `MessageHandler` called [`OAuthWebSecurity`](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/using-oauth-providers-with-mvc). OWIN provides a mechanism both to redirect and process the authentication provider callback; read [Creating Custom OAuth Middleware for MVC 5](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/creating-custom-oauth-middleware-for-mvc-5/) for more information.

### ClaimsAuthenticationManager

`ClaimsAuthenticationManager` isn't really what it sounds like. It really a tail-end aspect of an authentication process that has already been performed by the Windows Identity Foundation (WIF). It is meant to transform the Claim produced by that process to meet your custom needs. For example, the Claims list may include a username, from which you might look up from a database frequently-accessed roles or rights, and add these to the Claims list for performance reasons.

It is applicable anywhere WIF is used. Relative to current ASP.NET web applications, that will mean OWIN.

### Summary

Yeah. You'll probably be using OWIN, WIF, and cookies in your modern ASP.NET web  app. Just something to accept if you use the 'boxed materials', along with the death of WebForms and VB.NET in this release.

So, since you'll probably be doing OWIN authentication, here's an excellent series on the topic; [What’s this Owin Stuff About?](http://coding.abel.nu/series/owin-authentication/)

Comment: I'm out of the loop. Why "death of vb.net in this release" ?

Answer (score 3):

OWIN is more of a grander scope of minimizing the stack for serving web pages and minimizing the stack is the new wave of the future(ala node.js). **"OWIN authenication middleware"** is what you are referring to and **Brock Allen** states it best here:

http://brockallen.com/2013/10/24/a-primer-on-owin-cookie-authentication-middleware-for-the-asp-net-developer/

> With .NET 4.5.1, for ASP.NET applications, all the underlying code
>   that handles “Individual User Accounts” (as well as the templates in
>   Visual Studio 2013) is new. This means for cookie based authentication
>   we no longer use Forms authentication and for external identity
>   providers we no longer use DotNetOpenAuth.
>
> The replacement is a framework called OWIN authentication middleware
>   and it’s targeting the OWIN API. I don’t plan to motivate OWIN here
>   (this a good article on the subject), but in short it’s an abstraction
>   API for the web host. Many frameworks such as Web API and SignalR (as
>   well as other non-Microsoft frameworks) are coded to this abstraction
>   so they do not require any particular web host (such as IIS).

Comment: It took me almost a year to appreciate that this is actually as much of an answer to my question as could be expected, without more clarity. Unfortunately it doesn't really answer the question I had in my head at the time. Recently, I had a related question ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29349316/where-to-filter-identity-2-0-claim-ticket-in-a-webapi-app ) with an expired bounty, that finally forced me to get in and understand these components. I'll add an answer here soon, since it looks like others are also confused about this issue, perhaps in the same way I was.